# Access 2000 - Editor & Line numbers?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

Anyway to get Access 2K Module (vba code) editor to show line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of my favorite questions! .... please use MZ-Tools for that, and do not hesitate to send them some money! You can even use their tool to build a smart error handler, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357822/ms-access-vba-and-error-handling/357882#357882)

Comment: Looks great. I don't know how I didn't know about this utility all these years.