# VBA error handling and MZ-tools

Tags: vba, error-handling, automation

Thanks to reading about error handling on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357822/ms-access-vba-and-error-handling), I discovered Mz-Tools. However, I am wondering if there is a way to simultaneously update all the error handlers added by MZ-Tools.

If I add an error handler with MZ-Tools and then change the default error handler (via Options|Error Handler on the Mz-Tools toolbar), is there any way to have the changes automatically incorporated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  I'd use a good search and replace tool, that can replace blocks of code to do what you want.  I use HomeSite - it's a webdev tool, but has the most awesome search and replace capability.